# Drawing on desktop in Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, desktop

I want to create analog of program [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html). What is the best way to draw information on a OS X desktop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NSWindow has a method, `setLevel:`, that lets you control how the window is positioned compared to other windows. From my own experience, you might want to try feeding it `kCGDesktopIconWindowLevel`, and calling `setHasShadow:NO` to implement the look you want. To actually do the drawing you would put a custom NSView subclass in your window, and create the window without a frame (see `NSBorderlessWindowMask`) and transparent (`[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]], [self setOpaque:NO];`).

You might also want to take a [look at this article](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DontExposeMe) to keep your window pinned to the desktop during an Expose event.

Comment: The DontExposeMe hack breaks compatibility with Spaces. I wouldn't recommend it. Fortunately, if your window is at the desktop-icon level, Exposé shouldn't touch it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/)? Maybe you don't even have to write the app. ☺

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look at using `NSWindowLevel` with a transparent window.