# Send window to back?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm looking to send a window to the *very* back of the screen, as in just over the desktop.  Basically I'm wanting it to launch and never be above any other apps.  Is there a way to send the window to back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You´ll want to use NSWindowLevel, in specific kCGDesktopWindowLevel. A short overview on NSWindowLevel can be found [here](http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSWindowLevel), and a [more elaborate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982584/how-do-i-draw-the-desktop-on-mac-os-x/4987525#4987525) has been posted to a [similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982584/how-do-i-draw-the-desktop-on-mac-os-x) before.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for can be found [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/working-with-interface-windows-in-cocoa.html).

The section of interest is "Hiding and showing a window".

I apologise, if this is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I wanted it to be at the VERY bottom level.