# How to make a Window fix on the desktop in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing on desktop in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418791/drawing-on-desktop-in-mac-os-x)

Just like this:

http://ibuick.com/DesktopMonitor.html

Comment: See also: [How do I draw the desktop on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982584/how-do-i-draw-the-desktop-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

You simply use a borderless [NSWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (`NSBorderlessWindowMask`) and take it from there.

i.e.: Pass in `NSBorderlessWindowMask` as the styleMask when calling `initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:`

You'll also need to set the opacity/background colo(u)r via:

```
[yourWindow setOpaque:NO];
[yourWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
```