# How do you draw to the desktop in Lion?

Tags: objective-c, drawing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing on desktop in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418791/drawing-on-desktop-in-mac-os-x)

How can I draw directly to the desktop (behind the icons) in OSX Lion using objective c? I know it is possible because there are some applications in the app store that allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this question [Drawing on desktop in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418791/drawing-on-desktop-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You never draw directly to the desktop. The best you can do is to create a transparent window just above the desktop and draw in there.